# Not storing value to a variable

Tags: java, input, joptionpane

So, I'm still fairly new to Java and I'm having a hard time with this.
For a class, I'm having to write a program that will calculate a user's tax return amount (in no way is this actually accurate).
When I run this, it is not actually storing the annual income amount (stored in the userInput method). When I change it to `public userInput()`, it doesn't give me an error for the line:

```
double annualIncome = entry.nextDouble;
```

However, there's an error saying I should either change the method to a constructor, or change it to public void userInput, which then gives me an error saying the variable annualIncome is not user.

Could someone help me out with understanding why this is, how to fix it, and why that solution works?

I was also trying to accept user input via a dialog box, but since that only returns string values, I tried to convert annualIncome to a float or double so I could use it in the calcTax method by using Float.parseFloat(); and that was not storing any value either, I believe the answer to above would help me with this.

My next step after this is resolved is to make sure the program only moves forward if the `ssn` field follows a 111-11-1111 format, the zip field only has 5 numbers, the annualIncome is not negative (that would suck), and that the entry for maritalStatus starts with M, m, S, or s.

If someone could point me in the right direction with this portion would be much appreciated.
With all due respect, it's very hard to learn from my teacher.

I feel like I have the general structure of the code down:

```
package javaProgramming;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TaxReturn{
Scanner entry = new Scanner(System.in);

// Tax return data fields
String ssn;
String lastName;
String firstName;
String streetAddress;
String city;
String state;
String zip;
String maritalStatus;
double annualIncome;
float taxLiability;

public TaxReturn(){

}

// Not needed? Program runs the same when this part is taken out.
public TaxReturn(String ssn, String lastName, String firstName, String streetAddress, String city, String state, String zip, String maritalStatus, double annualIncome, float calculateTax){

    this.ssn = ssn;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.streetAddress = streetAddress;
    this.city = city;
    this.state = state;
    this.zip = zip;
    this.maritalStatus = maritalStatus;
    this.annualIncome = annualIncome;
    taxLiability = calculateTax;
}

// Used to get user input for Tax Return info
public void userInput(){
    System.out.println("What is your social security number?");
    ssn = entry.nextLine();
    System.out.println("What is your last name?");
    lastName = entry.nextLine();
    System.out.println("What is your first name?");
    firstName = entry.nextLine();
    System.out.println("What is your street address?");
    streetAddress = entry.nextLine();
    System.out.println("What city do you live in?");
    city = entry.nextLine();
    System.out.println("What state do you live in?");
    state = entry.nextLine();
    System.out.println("What's your zip code?");
    zip = entry.nextLine();
    System.out.println("What's your marital status?");
    maritalStatus = entry.nextLine();
    System.out.println("How much is your annual income?");
    double annualIncome = entry.nextDouble();


}

// Will calculate the tax rate depending on the user's income and marital status.
double calcTax(){
double rate = 0;
if(annualIncome >= 0 && annualIncome <= 20000){
    if (maritalStatus == ("Married"))
        rate = .14;
    else
        rate = .15;
} else if ((annualIncome >= 20001) && annualIncome <= 50000){
    if (maritalStatus == ("Married"))
        rate = .2;
    else
        rate = .22;
} else if (annualIncome >= 50001){
    if (maritalStatus == ("Married"))
        rate = .28;
    else
        rate = .3;
}
return annualIncome * rate;
}

// Displays a report for the user with their tax return amount based on what they entered.
public void returnData(){
    System.out.println("Name: " + firstName + " " + lastName
            + "\nAddress: " + streetAddress + " " + city + ", " + state + " " + zip
            + "\nMarital Status: " + maritalStatus
            + "\nAnnual Income: " + annualIncome
            + "\nTax return amount: $" + calcTax());
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    TaxReturn taxReturn1 = new TaxReturn();
    taxReturn1.userInput();
    taxReturn1.calcTax();
    taxReturn1.returnData();
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You're declaring your variable (double annual income) in the Method `userInput...`. This method is however a `public void` method meaning it does not return anything, but you need the double.  Change `public void userInput()` to `public double userInput()`:

```
 public double userInput(){
    System.out.println("What is your social security number?");
    ssn = entry.nextLine();
    System.out.println("What is your last name?");
    lastName = entry.nextLine();
    System.out.println("What is your first name?");
    firstName = entry.nextLine();
    System.out.println("What is your street address?");
    streetAddress = entry.nextLine();
    System.out.println("What city do you live in?");
    city = entry.nextLine();
    System.out.println("What state do you live in?");
    state = entry.nextLine();
    System.out.println("What's your zip code?");
    zip = entry.nextLine();
    System.out.println("What's your marital status?");
    maritalStatus = entry.nextLine();
    System.out.println("How much is your annual income?");
    this.annualIncome = entry.nextDouble();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using local variable here:

```
double annualIncome = entry.nextDouble();
```

just remove "double" to use what you want:

```
 annualIncome = entry.nextDouble();
```

for the est of you question: you need to check the formats for the inputs, it seems to be best to use regular expressions, something like:

```
System.out.println("What is your social security number?");
ssn = entry.nextLine();
while( ! (ssn.matches("^(\\d{3}-\\d{2}-\\d{4})$")) )
{
    System.out.println("Please enter ssn in 111-11-1111 format:");
    ssn = entry.nextLine();
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't he also add parenthesis since `nextDouble()` is a method of the `Scanner` class?

Comment: sure Riley, I don't know when it got lost :)

Answer (score 0):

wherever you are using instance variables, call them with "this." operator. check this edited code below. Its accepting the annual income and giving correct output. I hope I understood your question properly.

```
public class TaxReturn {
Scanner entry = new Scanner(System.in);
// Tax return data fields
String ssn;
String lastName;
String firstName;
String streetAddress;
String city;
String state;
String zip;
String maritalStatus;
double annualIncome;
float taxLiability;

public TaxReturn(){

}

// Not needed? Program runs the same when this part is taken out.
public TaxReturn(String ssn, String lastName, String firstName, String streetAddress, String city, String state, String zip, String maritalStatus, double annualIncome, float calculateTax){

    this.ssn = ssn;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.streetAddress = streetAddress;
    this.city = city;
    this.state = state;
    this.zip = zip;
    this.maritalStatus = maritalStatus;
    this.annualIncome = annualIncome;
    taxLiability = calculateTax;
}

// Used to get user input for Tax Return info
public void userInput(){
    System.out.println("What is your social security number?");
    this.ssn = entry.nextLine();
    System.out.println("What is your last name?");
    this.lastName = entry.nextLine();
    System.out.println("What is your first name?");
    this.firstName = entry.nextLine();
    System.out.println("What is your street address?");
    this.streetAddress = entry.nextLine();
    System.out.println("What city do you live in?");
    this.city = entry.nextLine();
    System.out.println("What state do you live in?");
    this.state = entry.nextLine();
    System.out.println("What's your zip code?");
    this.zip = entry.nextLine();
    System.out.println("What's your marital status?");
    this.maritalStatus = entry.nextLine();
    System.out.println("How much is your annual income?");
    this.annualIncome = entry.nextDouble();


}

// Will calculate the tax rate depending on the user's income and marital status.
public double calcTax(){
double rate = 0;
if(this.annualIncome >= 0 && this.annualIncome <= 20000){
    if (this.maritalStatus == ("Married"))
        rate = .14;
    else
        rate = .15;
} else if ((this.annualIncome >= 20001) && this.annualIncome <= 50000){
    if (this.maritalStatus == ("Married"))
        rate = .2;
    else
        rate = .22;
} else if (this.annualIncome >= 50001){
    if (this.maritalStatus == ("Married"))
        rate = .28;
    else
        rate = .3;
}
return this.annualIncome * rate;
}

// Displays a report for the user with their tax return amount based on what they entered.
public void returnData(){
    System.out.println("Name: " + this.firstName + " " + this.lastName
            + "\nAddress: " + this.streetAddress + " " + this.city + ", " + this.state + " " + this.zip
            + "\nMarital Status: " + this.maritalStatus
            + "\nAnnual Income: " + this.annualIncome
            + "\nTax return amount: $" + calcTax());
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    TaxReturn taxReturn1 = new TaxReturn();
    taxReturn1.userInput();
    taxReturn1.calcTax();
    taxReturn1.returnData();
}
}
```